# How does Stack Overflow save the questions and answers?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

How does Stack Overflow save the questions and answers? Does it use databases or bigdata solutions? What are the technologies used behind it and how does the search feature work so fast?

Comment: This might give you a "hint" ;)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: Silly question...of course it's backed by an Access database accessed via a VB6 application which emulates a webserver! ... Or it's unicorns all the way down...I can never remember.

Answer (score 1):

> and how does the search feature work so fast?

Indexing, indexing, indexing  .. correct indexes do the magic. [And Lucene](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/)

Comment: What actually does the magic: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/stack-overflow-search-now-81-less-crappy/